# Bootstrap items stretched ona large screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a page at the moment (http://johncashin.net/test_sites/MARC_Napier_test/#) and am having an issue with the size of objects on a certain screen size. 
When the user clicks on the items in the accordians, we are shown several cards of information. However on large screens, these cards are quite a bit wider than I would want, but bootstrap doesn't seem to have a class for wider screens. Ideally I would like the cards to collapse to 4 wide rather than 3, but can not find a way to do it through bootstrap. Any ideas? Bootply here. http://www.bootply.com/wVddNooKxd

Comment: How big a screen are we talking? Can you provide a screenshot of whats going on?

Comment: This is the page on a 1280 x 800 resolution. http://imgur.com/BZOgwhs
I've been making the page on this so far and its looking how I like it.
On a 1920 x 1080 resolution I get the first image here http://imgur.com/a/wyVtS#0 and on shortening the width on the 1280 x 800 screen I get the second image, which is far too cramped.

Answer (score 0):

For larger monitors use `col-lg-4`

Have a look at Shoelace, might help you out with what you're tying to achieve!
http://shoelace.io/